# Fetching user's auth status returns unexpected results

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I've been playing with (Vue) Apollo and so far I haven't had much trouble, especially working with remote data. Querying local data (state) is what's giving me a bit of an issue. I'm trying to fetch the user's auth status, but I'm having unexpected results, with the logged out response being `{data: null, loading: false, networkStatus: 7, stale: true}`.

I have included the relevant code snippets. Just for the record, I'm able to successfully log in and update the cache, specifically the auth status. Querying this auth info is my issue.

**Edit**: I should point out that (and I just noticed it) when I clear localStorage, deleting both the auth token and the current user, I get the expected `{ data: { authInfo: { isAuthenticated: false, currentUser: null } } }` printed out in the console. However, when logged in, with both the auth token and current user saved in the browser storage, I get the my `{ data: null, ...}` issue. Strange!

**Auth (local) state**

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

cache.writeData({
  data: {
    authInfo: {
        isAuthenticated: !!localStorage.getItem('token'),
        currentUser: localStorage.getItem('current-user') || null,
        __typename: 'Auth'
    }
  },
});

export default cache;
```

**Auth schema**

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const AUTH_INFO = gql`
  query AuthInfo {
    authInfo @client {
      isAuthenticated
      currentUser {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

**Auth query**

```
<script>
    import { AUTH_INFO } from '@/graphql/queries';

    export default {
      name: "home-page",
      methods: {
        async fetchAuthInfo() {
          try {
            const data = await this.$apollo.query({
              query: AUTH_INFO,
            });

            console.log(data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        },
      },
      created() {
        this.fetchAuthInfo();
      },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: what do you expect `fetchAuthInfo` to do? it fetches the data, then does nothing with it

Comment: It's not clear from your question what result you're getting and also what you were expecting. Also, the network response is irrelevant to your question since we're talking about local state. Please update your question with additional details.

Comment: @Bravo I need the isAuthenticated status to conditionally render signup/login/logout buttons. The console.log was to output what the response was when I noticed it wasn't working.

Comment: @DanielRearden The data property on the result object is null. I posted the screen capture of the corresponding network response. What I was expecting was `{ data: { authInfo: { isAuthenticated: true, currentUser: currentUserObject } } }`.

Comment: You're querying a single local (`@client`) field -- there will be no corresponding network response. The screenshot you posted is of an introspection query, which is unrelated to the `AuthInfo` query you're making.

Comment: That, it is. I just felt the need to post anything and everything related to the query in case anyone needed the info. Regardless, any idea why I'm getting a null data response?

Comment: What would be helpful to know is exactly what you're seeing in the console from the `console.log(data)` call.

Comment: That's logged out response `{data: null, loading: false, networkStatus: 7, stale: true}`. I'm working with apollo-client 2.6 and no, not working with apollo-link-state.

Comment: @DanielRearden I should point out that (and I just noticed it) when I clear localStorage, deleting both the auth token and the current user, I get the expected ``{ data: { authInfo: { isAuthenticated: false, currentUser: null } } }` printed out in the console from the query. However, when logged in, with both the auth token and current user saved in the browser storage, I get the my `{ data: null, ...}` issue. Strange!